# Ruby: multidimensional %w array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Could a multidimensional array be defined with a single `%w` directive?

For example:

```
the_array = %w(one two three{some separator}four five{some separator}six seven eight nine)
```

I need this to build an array with variable amount of items in a row:

```
the_array = [
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['four', 'five'],
    ['six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the inverse, use the short-hand word array notation in a standard array brackets.

```
the_array = [%w(one two three), %w(four five), %w(six seven eight nine)]
```

The goal of the short-hand word notation is to save all the punctuation in terms of commas and quotation marks.